# Отступы между объектом в таблице

Tags: html

[image: Пример]

При использование табличной верстки у изображения появляются боковые отсупы. 
Используя border-collapse: collapse и cellspacing="0" частично от них избавиться удалось. Но отступы в 1px всё же остались.

P.s: у объекта находящегося в таблице padding и margin обнулены.

```
<div class="mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-color--white" style="padding: 0 px">

<table style="border-collapse:collapse" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<tr>

<td width="40%" valign="top">
<div class="demo-card-image mdl-card" style="margin: 0">
<div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand"></div>
<div class="mdl-card__actions">
<span class="demo-card-image__filename">
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:white"><i class="material-icons align">favorite_border</i> 1 000</a>
<br>
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:white"><i class="material-icons align">chat_bubble_outline</i> 1 000</a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</td>

<td style="padding: 10px; padding-top: 0px" valign="top">
<h4>Денис Небесный</h4>
Родился: <strong>6 октября 1997 (19 лет)</strong>
<br>
Проживает: <img src="/images/country/3159.svg" height="25"> <strong>Российская Федерация, г.Омск</strong>
<br>
Семейное положение: <strong>Не женат</strong>
</td>

</tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: код добавть....

Comment: `border="0"` пробовали?

Comment: Да, пробовал...

Comment: а можете сюда сниппет добавить? Иными словами, создать минимальный воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: <div style="background:white"><table><tr><td><img></td><td>....</td></tr></table></div>